# Related questions change too often - can't find a related question I saw a pageview before

Tags: feature-request, related-questions

The "related" questions in a question (placed bottom right) are changing too often, almost per-refresh. What happens to me many times is that I hit back and next on browser to check something with the intention to get back immediately to the previous page and follow a related question I'm interested in. But when I'm getting back to that page, the related questions are different and the one I was interested in is no longer there.

I understand this happens for a reason, so (instead of making the related questions more "static") can you just add something like "more related questions" to the bottom so I can have the ability to see all the related questions and find the lost one that was displayed in a previous pageview?

Comment: Ooh. This looks interesting. And this looks interesting too. Click. Back. Oh noes! It changed.

Comment: @bjb568 exactly.

Comment: related or hot? [Hot questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hot-questions) at sidebar change by design: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229052/hot-network-questions-randomizes-too-much-when-navigation-in-browser-history

Comment: @gnat Oh god. 30% engagement? Sounds like an ad. If the goal is "engagement", I'll block it with adblock.

Comment: @bjb568 see [What is the Goal of “Hot Network Questions”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219922/165773)